# htaccess RewriteRule is not working in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, joomla2.5

In joomla project I have a page like this "localhost/joomla/ezlinks-part-info?brand=xyz&partid=MOT:D44-488JK"  for custom php code in my page. In that page I have included the .php file for some external functionality.

Now I want to display the url like "localhost/joomla/xyz/MOT:D44-488JK.html".

To get this I have used below RewriteRule in joomla htaccess

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9:-]+).html$ ezlinks-part-info?brand=$1&partid=$2 [L,QSA]

But 404 error showing in this page. If I use this rule in core php htacces it is working fine.

Can any one please guide me on this what can I do to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

.htacces

```
    ##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9:-]+)\.html$ ezlinks-part-info?brand=$1&partid=$2 [L,QSA]
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: Is mod_rewrite working? Do you get 500 Internal server error when putting some garbage inside `.htaccess`? Also paste full `.htaccess` contents.

Comment: Yes getting 500 internal server error. And pasted the .htacces content above.

Comment: Try moving your RewriteRule just after `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

Comment: Yes moved my RewriteRule as you said but not working.

Comment: It is rewriting on my test environment. I copy pasted your .htaccess and moved Rewrite rule as in my comment. I've also created file `ezlinks-part-info.php` with `<?php var_dump($_SERVER);`. Next I changed rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9:-]+)\.html$ ezlinks-part-info.php?brand=$1&partid=$2 [L,QSA]` (added `.php`) And it is rewriting it as shown in `$_SERVER`. You can check it by doing the same thing as me.

Comment: yeah piotrekkr, in core php file if we add this it will work. But my url "localhost/joomla/ezlinks-part-info" in joomla articla page.

Comment: I have applied this rule to one article page only.

Comment: Does it work when you access `http://localhost/joomla/ezlinks-part-info?brand=xyz&partid=MOT:D44-488JK` by browser? Also try change flags from `[L,QSA]` to `[QSA]`

Comment: Yeah working fine with above url.

Comment: Remove `L` flag so it will rewrite it first to `ezlinks-part-info?brand=xyz&partid=MOT:D44-488JK` and next it will be matched by next rules and rewritten to `index.php`. It should work.

Comment: yeah removed "L" flag. But no luck poitrekkr